# Web API Url is not working from Angular 2 application in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I am writing Angular 2 application by using Visual studio, and I took "ASP.NET Core Angular 2 Starter Application (Core)" template. So all things are already comes with created application.

I am trying to call web api in Angular 2 by using TypeScript as below code, But it's not calling, It's not hitting to the break point too.

```
public GetEntries(): Observable<RepeatList[]> {
        console.log("Call 2");
        return this.http.get('/breakout/GetEntries')
            .map(this.ParseData)
            .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
    }
```

When I put Api url in browser, It's giving me output. I am using below URL,

```
http://localhost:55482/breakout/GetEntries
```

My API is,

```
public class BreakoutController : BaseController{
[HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<RepeatList> GetEntries()
        {
            return _breakoutService.GetRepeatEntryNames("");
        }
}
```

What things I ned to change to make it call my API, I am not adding api/ in front of api call.

Comment: I replace Observable with Promise, and it starts working. Is there any way to make it work with Observable.?

Comment: You need to subscribe to the Observable. Wherever you are calling your `GetEntries` method in your angular application, you will need to do something like `GetEntries().subscribe(entries => { this.entries = entries; });`